# Laravel Eager Loading and Form Model Binding

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I have a User model and via Eager Loading i am loading also the Table Profile.

To Display it i just write `$user->profile->nameOfTheProfilePropertyIWant` just as normal.

Simple.

But how exactly do i use Form Model Binding now?
Normal i would use `Form::text('nameOfTheUserPropertyIWant')` for a User Property like an email. But i want to set in on a Property of the Profile like the location. (profile->location)

But how can i set it to an profile property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may do this (in a `one-to-one` relationship) using something like this:

```
Form::text('profile[location]')
```

In this case `$user->profile->location` will be populated in the given text box if an instance of `User` model is bound to the from using `Form::model($user)` with the related model `profile`.

Comment: You're the best! Thanks!

Comment: in case of one more level? Something like: $user->profile->location->x ?