# Laravel mass update

Tags: laravel-4

yesterday i asked a question about Eager Loading and Form Model Binding.
[Laravel Eager Loading and Form Model Binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23766283/laravel-eager-loading-and-form-model-binding)

This is somehow a followup question.

Now i want to update the record in the Database

```
    $user = \User::findOrFail($id);
    $user->fill(\Input::all());
    $user->push();
```

But this dose only save the data of the user itself. Not the relations

`user = saved`
`user->profile = not saved`

on my user model i have a fillable array with all fillables columns. and on other models like the profile model i just wrote `protected $fillable = ['*'];`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Soultion:

call fill() on the relations not just the user model.

```
$user->fill($input)
$user->profile->fill($input['profile'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not retrieving profile with your user model.

```
$user = \User::with('profile')->findOrFail($id);
```

That should give you the profile properties to update.

Comment: So, after '$user = \User::findOrFail($id);', you have something other than 'null' when you 'dd($user->profile)'?  Where are you loading the relative model(s)?